# Recursion to flatten an array not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was working on the steamroller problem of free code camp. I came up with two solutions: one works perfectly [1, 2, 3, 4], but the other is giving [ 4 ].

The problem asks to write a function that flatten any sort of array.

my working code:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
   newArr = [];
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === true) {
       newArr = newArr.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
     } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === false) {
       newArr.push(arr[i]);
     }
   }
   return newArr;
}
steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

my not working code:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  newArr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === true) {
      newArr.push(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
    } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === false) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Can anyone explain why the second code give only [4] ?

Comment: Could you use the freecodecamp chat for this question type?

Comment: yes Ican, but why not use this awesome website !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because in first code, you are using

`newArr = newArr.concat()` in which you are assigning it to local variable. So, even in recursion, the state will be stored.

But in second code, you are using `newArr.push()` and in recursion, you are again declaring `newArr=[]`;

That is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  let newArr = arr.slice(); //newArr is a copy of arr
  var result = []; //this is going to be the flatted array
  checkArray(newArr, result);
  return result;
}

function checkArray(myArray, resultedArray) {
  //this function is a a recursion
  return myArray.map(elt => {
    if (!Array.isArray(elt)) {
      //so this is a simple element, it is not an array, lets push it
      resultedArray.push(elt);
      return elt;
    } else {
      return checkArray(elt, resultedArray);
    }
  });
}
console.log(steamrollArray([1, {},
  [3, [
    [4]
  ]]
])); // should return [1, {}, 3, 4].
```

Comments in the code are helpful